# Xcode error "the project cannot be opened because it is in a future Xcode project file format."

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova

I have a macOS version 10.13.6, so the only version of Xcode I can download is 10.1.

Now when I create a new iOS project with Cordova and try opening it with Xcode, I get this error:

> The project at 'project-location' cannot be opened because it is in a future Xcode project file format. Adjust the project format using a compatible version of Xcode to allow it to be opened by this version of Xcode.

How can I adjust the project to run on Xcode version 10.1 if I can't open it in Xcode in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Cordova iOS Platform Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/ios/), Cordova requires Xcode 11 or later so you can't use it with Xcode 10.1.